# Checking if ActiveMq is persisting a message after changing the delivery mode of message to non persistent

Tags: activemq-classic

I am currently using activemq for my project. The problem I noticed that since a topic I used in activemq was persistent, I have the logs stored in kahadb. 
I tried changing the delivery mode of the message I sent to the topic as non persistent. But since kahadb stores the logs in a binary format there is no way to test if activemq is persisting the message or not. Can anyone suggest a suitable way to check if the activemq message has been persisted or not?

-------Edited After having a solution-----
I used a hack to test if the activemq message has been persisted. My topic had just one non durable subscriber. I created a durable subscriber, and kept it inactive as I passed the message to the concerned topic. Then I stopped the activemq server. If the message has been persisted, the message will again be fetched and will appear in the pending queue for the durable subscriber created. This is the hack I used to test if the message has been persisted in the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Topic messages are not persisted unless you have a durable subscription, if you do then you should be able to see them using [JMX MBeans](http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html) or via the [web console](http://activemq.apache.org/web-console.html).  A Topic itself will never have its messages persisted to the store for the non-durable consumer case.

There is an [ActiveMQ CLI](https://github.com/apache/activemq-cli-tools) to export data from KahaDB which could aid you in seeing what is actually going into your store if you really need to see everything:

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Your inputs helped me in finding out whether a message is persisted for a topic. The hack that I followed are in the edited section of the my question. However, I believe that the messages are persisted for a topic if the delivery mode of message is set to persistent, irrespective of the topic having just a non-durable subscriber. Its just that activemq doesn't use the persisted message again. Please correct me if I am wrong in this regards.

Comment: You are wrong, topic messages are discarded without ever going to disk if there is not a durable subscription on that Topic to direct the broker to save them.

Comment: Isn't persistence a property of the message being sent? Does it mean that topics in activemq do not honor the property of the message? Sorry for such questions, but I am new to activemq so interested in knowing about it.

Comment: The message can be marked as persistent but unless there is a **DURABLE** subscription on the Topic the message is tossed if there's nobody to received it regardless of the persistent flag, you need to understand the difference be durable and non-durable subscriptions for Topics.